# Limiting Directory Navigation in Electron Apps

Tags: javascript, security, electron

I'm creating an electron application that is designed to take untrusted code and attempt to execute it in an iframe (the code is in a custom format which specifies the composition of "modules" the application is designed to use). I am struggling to find a solution where I can use the iframe to sandbox the untrusted code, and allow it to access some but not all of the application's files. For example, I have JQuery in the app source code, as well as TinyMCE. These would be useful tools to allow the iframe access to.

I can use `<iframe src="Sandbox/index.html" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"></iframe>`,
however I cannot prevent the iframe from having access to just about any file it might want, and by extension the same problem exists for the entire renderer process. For example, let's say I have a directory structure like this:

```
Projects/
  sneakysecrets.js
  ElectronProject/
    index.js - (main process)
    page.html - (host for the iframe)
    Sandbox/
      iframecontent.html
```

inside sneakysecrets.js:

```
console.log('escape detected');
```

and inside the body of iframecontent.html:

```
<script src="../../sneakysecrets.js"></script>
```

If I set the iframe element in page.html like this (allow-same-origin):

```
<iframe src="Sandbox/index.html" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"></iframe>
```

then I have access to everything inside the application directory. And, I assumed, nothing more. But interestingly, in the console I see `escape detected`! How do I limit the access any render process has to files within (and outside of!) the project?

If I remove `allow-same-origin` from the iframe, it cannot access the tools in the application that it needs

My ideal goal is to setup electron to treat a certain subdirectory in the project as the "Server", and prevent navigation outside of that. But despite efforts I cannot find any documentation relating to limiting OS navigation in this case. So, I'm either missing something, or this is just an inherent vulnerability that I cannot avoid, and I should adjust my approach.

Comment: It seems as though you're searching for a way to home-brew your own isolation solution when there is already one: Electron is designed to separate renderer processes into isolation contexts. Take a look at [its documentation on `contextBridge`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge). It's best practice not to allow the renderer to access to NodeJS APIs at all.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner I am not exposing the node API in the renderer context, the renderer has access to *files* without it. See above, I used the standard html script/resource inclusion mechanisms (<script src="../../file-that-shouldnt-be-accessible.js"></script>) to access files *outside* of the project directory. I'm trying to achieve access control, not scope isolation.